# Can't call the Elements() method for System.Xml.Linq in Webmatrix site

Tags: asp.net, linq, razor, webmatrix

I followed the tutorial [Consuming and Storing Data from a REST Service with ASP.NET Razor](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/consuming-and-storing-data-from-a-rest-service-with-aspnet-razor#) but when running it I get this ASP.NET error:

```
CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Elements' and no extension method 'Elements' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Referring to this line:

```cs
var maxTemp = from t in xdoc.Descendants("temperature").Elements("value")
              where t.Parent.Attribute("type").Value == "maximum"
              select t;
```

Which seems to indicate that `Elements()` is not a recognized method, even though [Microsoft says it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

When I `Show Detailed Compiler Output` it says, among other things:

`C:\Windows\system32> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"`

However later it says:

`Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5`

In my Webmatrix `Settings` it shows I'm using `.NET 4 (Integrated)` and `ASP.NET Web Pages 2.0.20710.0`

All this C# code is in the `@functions{}` block in the `~\App_Data\Weather.cshtml` file.

My `Default.cshtml` file contains this:

```
@using System.Xml.Linq
@{
var temp = Weather.GetWeather("98052");
}
<ol>
    <li>Zip code: @temp.Zip</li>
    <li>High: @temp.MaxTemp</li>
    <li>Low: @temp.MinTemp</li>
    <li>Forecast: @temp.Forecast</li>
    <li>Longitude: @temp.Longitude</li>
    <li>Latitude: @temp.Latitude</li>
</ol>
```

What am I doing wrong?

(BTW, I followed the suggestions at the end of the tutorial and they didn't work either. I googled this for hours yesterday and tried a few things in the `web.config` file but it didn't help, at best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
var maxTemp = from t in xdoc.Descendants("temperature").Elements("value") where t.Parent.Attribute("type").Value == "maximum" select t;
```

with:

```
var maxTemp = from t in xdoc.Descendants("temperature")
                  where t.Attribute("type").Value == "maximum" 
                  select new{value= t.Element("value").Value};
```

if you want first record try this:

```
var maxTemp = (from t in xdoc.Descendants("temperature")
                  where t.Attribute("type").Value == "maximum" 
                  select new{value= t.Element("value").Value}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Now it compiles but it throws a runtime exception: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when executing `var maxTemp = from t in xdoc.Descendants("value") where t.Parent.Attribute("type").Value == "maximum" select t;` (I tried with both your suggestions). Is it because it's not getting anything from the XML doc?

Comment: can you share xml file

Comment: You'll see the XML file by going here: [weather service](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdBrowserClientByDay.php?listLatLon=47.6801,-122.121&format=24+hourly&numDays=1).

Comment: Almost works 100% now. Only that I was doing `FirstOrDefault()` further down, but now that you have that in the `select` I took it out. Still having a problem with the `Descendants()` method.

Comment: But that's really beyond my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with following:

```
int maxTemp = (int)xdoc.Root
                       .Element("data")
                       .Element("parameters")
                       .Elements("temperature")
                       .FirstOrDefault(t => (string)t.Attribute("type") == "maximum")
                       .Element("value");
```

Comment: I appreciate your jumping in. It came a minute late, though.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the code with the following, after that it worked wel :

```
    var maxTemp = from XElement in xdoc.Descendants("temperature").Elements("value")
                where XElement.Parent.Attribute("type").Value == "maximum"
                select XElement;  

    var minTemp = from XElement in xdoc.Descendants("temperature").Elements("value")
                where XElement.Parent.Attribute("type").Value == "minimum"
                select XElement;
```